# jquery dynamically add input checkbox with disabled and uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery

it is strange!

when i create a dynamic input(checkbox type), i can control checked is true or false, but when i create it with disable default, it sets input to checked!

here is my code:

```
var theInput = new $('<input>', {
  id: 'myCheckbox',
  name: 'myCheckbox',
  type: "checkbox",
  disabled: true,
  checked: false
});
theInput.uniform();
```

it adds disabled but checked input,

```
var theInput = new $('<input>', {
  id: 'myCheckbox',
  name: 'myCheckbox',
  type: "checkbox",
  disabled: true,
  checked: true
});
theInput.uniform();
```

if i set checked to true, then it adds disabled and unchecked input why?

**i changed "checked" to checked, but there is no diffrence.**

**i complete my code, problem is in uniform, when i uniform it, it changed property!**

Comment: did you try to change "checked" to checked

Comment: Both versions do what they should do for me in Google Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: why is "checked" a string? `checked:true` should work just fine

Comment: @Manish Jangir Blogaddition.com no diffrence

Comment: @Chris chroem Version 31.0.1650.63 m

Comment: I'm using the same Chrome, and it works fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xsu7T/

Comment: I can't replicate either issue using the same version of Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/ACn7f/

Comment: @Chris you are right thank you problem was in uniform, let me check why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a fiddle. Please check might help you. This is working. You can check this by changing checked to true or false in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Wc78K/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#containerId')
    .append(
       $(document.createElement('input')).attr({
           id:    'myCheckbox'
          ,name:  'myCheckbox'
          ,value: 'myValue'
          ,type:  'checkbox'
          ,disabled: true
          ,checked: true
       })
    );
});
```

Comment: it is not disabled!. problem is when i set disable to true

Comment: please check now. Changed the fiddle.

Comment: Great!  If the answer helped you please select it as correct. So that it can help other.